# Two Authentications For RESTful Services

Tags: web-services, security, rest, restful-authentication

We have a central RESTful webservices application that exposes data to many different clients (parsers, web applications, touch applications, etc). The clients have different means for authenticating users, some LDAP, others not. Regardless, the RESTful application leaves the authentication of the end-user to the client, and simply authenticates the client making the request. The client will have a username and password in LDAP, along with a list of acceptable IP addresses from which the client can access the RESTful application.

Here is the tricky part: the RESTful application must audit every request with the end-user's username. Furthermore, in certain circumstances (depending on the client) the RESTful application will need the end-user's username and password for accessing a third-party application. So, every request from the client will have authentication credentials for the client itself and the end-user accessing the client.

Here comes the question. Would it be best to put the client's credentials in Basic Auth, and pass the end-user's credentials via an encrypted SALT request parameter? Or, should the client put both sets of credentials in the Basic Auth (i.e. system~username:systempwd~userpwd) and parse them out into two sets of tokens that are then authenticated. Or, another solution that is better than either of these two?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds pretty much like OAuth2's "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant" - see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3. You pass application/client credentials in the Authorization header and client information in the body encoded using x-www-url-encoded. Do that once at the beginning of the session and then depend on a bearer token in the authorization header after that. All of that is described in the RFC. Remember to use SSL/TLS to encrypt the credentials.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful information. Here are a few caveats. One, we need to do authentication on every request, no state is stored on the RESTful webservices application. Two, the content-type will often need to be "application/json" for POST/PUT payloads that contain JSON data updating a resource. So, I am not sure the OAuth2 solution quite fits the use case. Any other ideas? Again, thank you for the help.

Comment: Well, if you really won't store any kind of state on the intermediate webservice application, then, yes, you will have to pass both client and user credentials on every request. In this case I would stick client credentials in the Authorization header (emulating OAuth2) and reserve a JSON property for user credentials in every request. Something like this: { user_credentials: { name: "John", pwd: "abcde" }, ... other payload ... }. Have fun :-)

Comment: Well, it's not really our choice. The third party application that the RESTful webservices often calls requires username/password of the end-user for any updates (create, update, delete). So an access token, in the case of OAuth2, wouldn't be useful because we would need the exact username and password of the end-user to pass validation on the third party software. I heard yesterday that the third party software may be planning to move to OAuth. Here's hoping that comes sooner rather than later :) Thank you Jorn.